# Fill ASP Form with Javascript (Android Studio)

Tags: javascript, java, android, asp.net, android-studio

I'm pretty new to Android studio, but I've already tried so many things, now I jsut have to ask.
I'd like to fill out an ASP.NET Website-form with android studio.
The "classical" Javascript-method doesn't seem to work here.

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: document.getElementByTagName('Benutzername').value = 'test'");
```

as well as

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByName('<%= Benutzername.ClientId %>').value = '"+username+"';");
```

Isn't working :/

The HTML-Text of the input field is:

```
<input name="Benutzername" type="text" style="text-align: center;  width:120px;border:solid 1px #6699CC;" onkeypress="{if (event.keyCode == 13){document.form1.Passwort.focus()};}" value="">
```

In source, I can find this code:

```
<td width="109" height="30"><div align="right" class="Stil12"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font size="3"><font size="2">Passwort:</font></font></font></div></td>
            <td width="126"><input name="Passwort" type="password" style="text-align: center; width:120px;border:solid 1px #6699CC;"
            onKeyPress="{if (event.keyCode == 13){if (Feldpruefung()) submit();};}" value="">
            </td>
```

But I jsut can't get it to work, and "simualting keypresses" also doesn't seem to be a usable way...
Anybody got some ideas?

Comment: Your first approach should work, I have done it before. could you provide the lines of code related to your webview ?

Comment: And does this line work? : myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('test');'");

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The alert isn't workeing either...? Maybe I've implemented the webView element wrongly?                                
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  <- ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably is related to your webview **settings**. Put the following code after  initialization of you webview.

```
WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()());
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

And if you want to call some method of your Java side from JS, you need to use **JavascriptInterface**. Take a look at [this link](https://www.codexpedia.com/android/javascript-interface-for-android-and-javascript-communication/).

About this line: **document.getElementByTagName**, the function you are calling does not exist, try this one:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('some_name')[0].value = 'some_value';
```

Comment: Let me know if it helps please.

Comment: Hi, I just created a new application and implemented your changes, the website laods, but the alert code still isn't working :/  https://www.pastiebin.com/5bb1d806ab5fc

Comment: I added a line to my answer, how about now ?

Comment: Didn't work :/ But I've dounf something inside the Logcat: com.example.noahk.webviewtest I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token", source: https://www.google.com/   --> Is myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('test');'");  probably the problem?

Comment: In my previous code, I've found the error: document.getElementByTagName is not a function; And "invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: Okay, now the alert works, there jsut seemed to be a typing error in alert('test');'" (one ' too much), but getElementByTagName still doesnt work; Is there an alternative, because the site i'm trying to automate hasn't got any ids tags, just names...

Comment: If I now implement ---> myWebView.loadUrl("document.getElementsByName('Benutzername')[0].value='Test'"); --> it results in a white webView window, but I can't find any errors...

Comment: About your last comment, if this line of JS call (document.getElementsByName('Benutzername')[0].value='Test') results error, the other ones won't get executed. it's probably the reason you see a white screen. About the error you get on the line of (document.getElementByTagName) it's actually **getElementsByTagName** (s after element) and you're getting JS error. Let me know if the issue is resolved please

Comment: And also for running JS, add 'javascript:' at the beginning of your command myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('Benutzername')");

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined", source: https:/.... --> Comes up when calling myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('Passwort')[0].value='Test'");  But this should be fine, ?!

Comment: The code of the input field is: <input name="Benutzername" type="text" style="text-align: center;  width:120px;border:solid 1px #6699CC;" onkeypress="{if (event.keyCode == 13){document.form1.Passwort.focus()};}" value="">

Comment: The Error you get shows that JS is running, the error reveals that there is no element with name of ''Passwort'. Are you sure that the name isn't 'Password'?

Comment: Yes, there I just checked if it's a problem with the input field. You can look up the website here : goo.gl/yYudKS ; the site in trying to automate is under the "BiblioWeb" link in the top right corner.

Comment: The problem is "frame", your input text is inside a frame, so you have to do following to access and change your input element value: **var mainFrame = document.getElementsByName("mainFrame")[0]; var pas = mainFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByName("Passwort")[0];pas.value = "1"**  This should resolve your problem. run each command inside a separated **myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:JS_COMMAND");** line.

Comment: :DDD Thank you so much! It now worked ^o^ I'll have to dig in a bit deeper and see if I find any more problems :) It worked by adding ; null // to the last command!

Comment: sia gut ! ( if I have written correctly :-D ) don't hesitate to leave comments if new relevant problem came up. good luck bro

Comment: Could you maybe also tell me how to properly extract text from a site? I don't want the whole HTML-code. Is it possible to extract the values read by js? a.e. reading an input field or a header from the site to check if navigation's correct... (If the url doesn't change); Because the website's url isn't changing while navigating/Filling forms :/

Comment: Of course, I have done a project in this way. I strongly do not recommend this, because by every even small change on your HTML from server side, you have to check JS codes from Android to avoid problems. Try a simple Rest API instead for getting and setting data, it's extremely more light-weight too. Anyway you have to check the tag name/id your data is placed in your HTML, and by document.getElement... try to search for it. Explain more about what exactly you want.

Comment: I'll try to use the rest API, but how can I get a value from ("Javascript:getelementby..."), I now know I can set it by changing a webview loading URL, but this seems to be only one-sided...?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, use javascriptinterface in your Java side

Comment: Hi, the problem is, that I can't edit the code of the website. I just need to read a value tag to display it inside the android app... I downloaded the tutorial you linked before, but this is only working bychanging the code of the website itself..?

Comment: What if there's another Frame inside the MainFrame? myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:var MainFrame = document.getElementsByName('mainFrame')[0];");
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:var MidFrame = MainFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByName('MidFrame')[0];");
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:var pas = MainFrame.MidFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByName('Number')[0];");
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:pas.value = '1158'; null"); This isn't working :/

Comment: window.frames['MidFrame'].document.getElementsByName('Mediennummer')[0].value='Test';  Works inside my normal browser, but gets the error "cannot read property document of undefined" inside android...

Comment: I guess I'd have to call document.getElementsByTagName('frame') inside another document.getElementsByTagName('frame')[1]? Because there's a frame called midFrame inside the mainFrame, but how to do that?